# how to link custom menu to author.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a new custom menu and this menu is link to author.php in wordpress. I have try some techniques but I still can't get the result.

I hope everyone here can help me.

Comment: Start by reading [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) or [try improving your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```js
You can get author.php via below steps: 

1) Create a custom menu url like: http://example.com/apage/?mydata=thisdata
2) Then get paramenter   $myvalue = $_GET('mydata');
<?php 
 $myvalue = $_GET('mydata');

if($myvalue)
  {
     header('Location: FILE PATH');
  }

?>

Hope this trick will help you
```